# Anchor Tabs not being applied to document sent via DocuSign using .NET SOAP API

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, soap, docusignapi

I've been trying to get Anchor Tabs working using the DocuSign SOAP API via .NET. I have successfully gotten normal tabs to work using a similar method (minus the AnchorTabItem code of course).

When the document is sent with the anchor tabs specified, the tabs do not show up on the document for any of the recipients. Instead, each recipient is able to put their own signature tabs onto the document, as shown below:

[image: docusign anchor tabs]

When I attempt to use the web interface to create anchor tabs on a template it works perfectly and finds the text on the document that I am specifying in the `Row("anchorString")` variable. Below is the code I'm using to add the tabs and assign them to a document ID and recipient ID. `Data.Tab.GetTabsByDocName` is used to get tab positions and recipient roles.

```
    Dim DT As DataTable = Data.Tab.GetTabsByDocName(DocName)
    Dim Tabs As New List(Of DemoDocuSign.Tab)
    For Each Row As DataRow In DT.Rows
        Dim Tab As New DemoDocuSign.Tab With {.AnchorTabItem = New DemoDocuSign.AnchorTab()}
        With Tab
            .Type = [Enum].Parse(GetType(DemoDocuSign.TabTypeCode), Row("type"))
            .TabLabel = Row("role")
            .PageNumber = Row("pageNum")
            .AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = Row("anchorString")
            .AnchorTabItem.IgnoreIfNotPresent = False
            .AnchorTabItem.IgnoreIfNotPresentSpecified = True
            .AnchorTabItem.Unit = DemoDocuSign.UnitTypeCode.Cms
            .AnchorTabItem.UnitSpecified = True
            .AnchorTabItem.YOffset = Row("yOffset")
            .AnchorTabItem.XOffset = Row("xOffset")
        End With
    Next
    If Recipients IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each Recipient In Recipients
            For Each Tab In Tabs
                If Recipient.Role = Tab.TabLabel Then
                    Tab.RecipientID = Recipient.RecID
                End If
                Tab.DocumentID = Document.DocID
            Next
        Next
        Dim FinalTabs As New List(Of DemoDocuSign.Tab)
        For Each Tab In Tabs
            If Tab.RecipientID <> "" Then
                FinalTabs.Add(Tab)
            End If
        Next
        Tabs = FinalTabs
    End If
    Return Tabs
```

I have no idea why this may be happening and I'm not getting any errors from the SOAP endpoint, the tabs just simply don't appear for the recipients.

Below is the XML of the request (with sensitive information omitted with ***). It seems like there are no tabs being attached at all, even though I use the same method I usually do!:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2014-01-21T22:31:01.565Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2014-01-21T22:36:01.565Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-cfaefba6-85c2-43e5-a3b8-cc6daa8cbf44-1">
                <o:Username>***</o:Username>
                <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">***</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <CreateAndSendEnvelope xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
            <Envelope>
                <AccountId>***</AccountId>
                <Documents>
                    <Document>
                        <ID>998</ID>
                        <Name>***.pdf</Name>
                    </Document>
                </Documents>
                <Recipients>
                    <Recipient>
                        <ID>1998</ID>
                        <UserName>Martin</UserName>
                        <Email>*@gmail.com</Email>
                        <Type>Signer</Type>
                        <AccessCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                    </Recipient>
                    <Recipient>
                        <ID>1999</ID>
                        <UserName>Test</UserName>
                        <Email>a@b.com</Email>
                        <Type>Signer</Type>
                        <AccessCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                    </Recipient>
                </Recipients>
                <Tabs/>
                <Subject>***</Subject>
                <EmailBlurb>Please sign the attached document for ****.</EmailBlurb>
                <Notification>
                    <Reminders>
                        <ReminderEnabled>true</ReminderEnabled>
                        <ReminderDelay>2</ReminderDelay>
                        <ReminderFrequency>2</ReminderFrequency>
                    </Reminders>
                </Notification>
            </Envelope>
        </CreateAndSendEnvelope>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

EDIT: It was because I didn't I didn't have Tabs.Add(Tab) to add each tab to my list...dumb mistake!

Comment: Something must be wrong with the XML request that's being sent to DocuSign.  Can you update your question to include the XML request body that your code is generating (and sending to DocuSign)?  You can easily produce a trace of the XML request by using Fiddler or a similar tool.

Comment: Since it's not finding any anchor tab strings in your document for some reason, the signing session turns into what's known as a Free Form Signing session.  Basically when no tabs at all are added to the envelope you get that drop down and are able to add signature tabs where ever you want in the document.  As Kim has stated, add the XML of your request (remove the document bytes if you'd like) and that should help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks I've added the XML request as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the XML request body.  So, DocuSign is behaving exactly as expected when your XML request body specifies no tabs for the recipient(s) -- i.e., it's giving the recipient(s) a "free form" signing experience, whereby they can simply drag/drop tags where ever they choose to.

In your XML request, I don't see a **Role** property for either **Recipient** -- this could be the source of your problem.  i.e., in your code, it looks like whether or not a tab gets added to the **FinalTabs** collection is dependent upon **Tab.RecipientID** being populated...which is dependent upon Recipient.Role being populated (and matching Tab.TabLabel).

```
...
If Recipient.Role = Tab.TabLabel Then
    Tab.RecipientID = Recipient.RecID
End If
...
For Each Tab In Tabs
    If Tab.RecipientID <> "" Then
        FinalTabs.Add(Tab)
    End If
Next
...
```

So, I'd suggest that you start by verifying that **Recipient.Role** is being populated correctly for each recipient. If that doesn't resolve your problem, I'd suggest that you step through your code in debug mode (examining property/collection values along the way) to determine what it is about your data (specifically, contents of **DT.Rows** and **Recipients**) that's resulting in no tabs being added to the XML request.

Comment: Thanks for this, it led me in the right direction in that I didn't have ``Tabs.Add(Tab)`` to add each tab to my list...dumb mistake!